# Android NDK Math functions not working

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

A am using Android Studio and the NDK in my app and I am having issues with some math functions, such as sinf, cosf, and sqrtf. When I use these functions they seem to just return 0.

I have `#include<math.h>` in the top of my file, and I attempted to link the math library in build.gradle, but it didn't change anything.

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.gl2jni"
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 5

        ndk {
            moduleName "libgl2jni"
            ldLibs "GLESv2","log","m"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
            cFlags "-fexceptions -std=gnu++11 -frtti -lm"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
One problematic area of code:

```
rotation = sinf(phase * 25.0f) * 0.4f;
phase += deltaTime;
```

I expect rotation to go back and forth, along a sin curve, between -1 and 1, but it stays constant. It isn't a problem with delta time, if I change it to `rotation = deltaTime;` it continually goes up.

EDIT 2:

Any code that uses math.h functions.

A basic example could be:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <android/log.h>

void SomeFunction(){
    //Should be 0
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Math Test", "%f", sinf(0.0f));
    //Should be 1
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Math Test", "%f", sinf(3.14f * 0.5f));
}
```

Comment: Show a concise, buildable example of code which returns an unexpected result.

Comment: Your second example seems to work fine me.  See if you can reduce it to an actual complete codebase (graft into hello-jni sample, or build as a native executable which is what I tried) and still have the problem.

Comment: From my Google searches it seems that I need to add a linking area to my build.gradle that tells it to actually link the math library, but I couldn't figure out how. I read that the problem is that since it isn't actually linking it defaults to an empty int function.

Comment: it would be worth running ndk-build from the command line to force using your Android.mk rather than the one that may be unhelpfully auto-generated. But I believe the issue you are referring to is one that can result from a missing include - without a *prototype* a function is assumed to have no arguments and return int.  But failing to *link* the function should normally be a fatal build error.  In terms of obscurities, you could I suppose somehow hit a hard/soft float mismatch.  But I think you should build the hello-jni ndk sample with your "Math test" code in it to try.

Comment: I tried it in the hello-jni sample and it worked without even needing to tell it to use the math library. I went back to my original application and logged a few different things and found that I didn't initialize `phase` to 0 and it defaulted to the max value.